# Server for HTML5 Websocket

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0, websocket

My application (HTML5 Websocket with ASP.net/C#) work's fine in my local server. I need to upload (deploy) my HTML5 websocket application in to the external server. Which server support ASP.net/C# HTML5 Websocket?

I need a best server to upload my application without any error.

Comment: This previous question looks like it answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014987/using-websockets-in-a-c-web-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using WebSockets in a C# Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014987/using-websockets-in-a-c-web-application)

Comment: If it works locally then what errors are you getting when you deploy to your "external" server?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options, and hosting providers.  My preferred choice is running on a Linux server using Mono. Linux generally cheaper and more flexible.